# Why is pd.Series called twice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was going through some solutions for an online code for sorting a series . In this case, why is pd.Series called twice ? what is the point when it seems to create the same series?

import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['100', '200', 'python', '300.12', '400'])

print("Original Data Series:")

new_s = pd.Series(s).sort_values()

print(new_s)

also, why does pd.apply(pd.Series) create a Dataframe? Thank you!!

Comment: `what is the point when it seems to create the same series?` I think not necesary, `new_s = s.sort_values()` working same

Comment: Sometimes when you get code online, it does pointless things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for first is new `Series` constructor reduntant:

```
s = pd.Series(['100', '200', 'python', '300.12', '400'])

new_s = s.sort_values()
print (new_s)
0       100
1       200
3    300.12
4       400
2    python
dtype: object
```

Reason, why is created one column DataFrame is for each element of Series processing by [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) is created one element `Series` what is joined together. So then is created `DataFrame`:

```
print (s.apply(pd.Series))
        0
0     100
1     200
2  python
3  300.12
4     400

#working same like s.apply(pd.Series)
print (s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)))
        0
0     100
1     200
2  python
3  300.12
4     400
0    100
dtype: object

#test output for each element
print (s.apply(lambda x: print(pd.Series(x))))
0    200
dtype: object
0    python
dtype: object
0    300.12
dtype: object
0    400
dtype: object
```

But better code for Series to one column Dataframe is use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
print (s.to_frame())
        0
0     100
1     200
2  python
3  300.12
4     400
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply write it this way:

s = pd.Series(['100', '200', 'python', '300.12', '400'])

new_s = s.sort_values()

print(new_s)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary. The following code should work fine:

```
s = pd.Series(['100', '200', 'python', '300.12', '400'])
print(s.sort_values())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > what is the point when it seems to create the same series?

It is not needed but i suspect that the original source have missed two print statements from their code. I believe it should be:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['100', '200', 'python', '300.12', '400'])

print("Original Data Series:")
print(s)

new_s = s.sort_values()

print("Sorted Data Series:")
print(new_s)
```

If the aim is to show how a series of non-uniform datatypes are sorted.

2. > why does pd.apply(pd.Series) create a Dataframe?

If I assume that you meant for a given series `s` and a function `some_func` that returns a Series object, then why does `s.apply(some_func)` return a DataFrame, then the answer is the the apply function works on each value of the series and if you return a series for each value you have effectively created series of series or a dataframe as i like to think about it. This is talked about in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

> Returns: Series or DataFrame
>
> If func returns a Series object the result will be a DataFrame.